# jQuery. Поменять цвет у одного элемента в зависимости от значения data другого

Tags: jquery

Помогите решить задачу. Как с помощью jQuery вывести элементы после основного div'а и менять их цвета в зависимости от значения "data-id" родительского div (от 1 до 6)? 
На выходе должны получиться значения skills с градацией цвета.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhsqtec/

```js
$('.ui-core-skill-name').after('<div class="dot-max"></div><div class = "dot-mid"></div><div class="dot-min"></div> ');

var dir = $(this).data("id");
if (dir == "1") {
  $('.dot-max').css({
    'backgroundColor': '#000'
  });
}
```

```css
.ui-core-skill {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.ui-core-skill-name {
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
}

.dot-max {
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 5px;
}

.dot-mid {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 5px;
}

.dot-min {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-core-skill">
  <div class="ui-core-skill-name" data-id="1">
    <h3>Skill name</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-core-skill-name').each(function(){
  var dir = $(this).data("id");
  if (dir == "1") {
    $(this).closest('.ui-core-skill').find('.dot-max').css({'backgroundColor' : '#000'});
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо, а если одновременно поменять цвета у .dot-max и .dot-mid?

Comment: @SvetaPershay то они, наверное, поменяются у обоих элементов